# i have app on angular 8 its very big app can i upgrade my app on angular 10

Tags: angular

How can I upgrade my application on Angular 8 to Angular 10? Should I need to make a new angular 10 application and copy paste every components and change accordingly or is there any other suitable method?
I use many solution about for this but a lot of error gain from modules
this is my package.json file

```
    {
  "name": "equality-mh",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc -p src -w",
    "start": "live-server --open=src",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-aot": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --configuration=production"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.26",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^8.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.7.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "adyen-api-js": "^1.30.4",
    "angular-6-social-login": "^1.1.1",
    "angular-google-charts": "^0.1.6",
    "angular-morris-js": "^1.1.0",
    "angular-tinymce": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-image-zoom": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2-masonry": "^0.4.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^2.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "imagesloaded": "^4.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jw-angular-social-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "^7.0.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng6-file-upload": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "ngx-editor": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-emoji-picker": "0.0.2",
    "ngx-facebook": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^2.0.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^8.0.1",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^2.1.1",
    "ngx-skeleton-loader": "^1.2.6",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.0.2",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.3.0",
    "stripe-angular": "^1.1.0",
    "swiper": "^5.2.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.0.14",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read https://update.angular.io/ and https://next.angular.io/guide/updating-to-version-10?

Comment: @Giannis yes i follow all steps but not working

Comment: So, do you really think copying every single component is a solution? What do you mean by not working? Why not specifying the particular problems you have?

Comment: @Giannis because i getting alot of errors how can i show you

Comment: Please check the answer carefully. Do NOT update from version 8 to 10 directly. After following the right instructions, please show any errors you have.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be upgrading from Angular 8 to 10 directly. Instead, first update to Angular 9 following the instructions here: https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3

Next, update to Angular 10 using these instructions: https://update.angular.io/#9.0:10.0l3

If you actually set it to update from 8 to 10 you'll get a small warning:

[image]

Comment: i followed all the steps of this link 
https://update.angular.io/#8.2:10.0 but not working

Comment: @rajpootrehan That's the point, don't do that. Upgrade to Angular 9, then 10.

Comment: after update use this steps gain a lot of errors form modules like
angular material, flex-layout, image-lazy-load and others